# Magento ->Tell if user logged in using straight SQL

Tags: sql, magento, expressionengine

How can I tell if a user is logged in using straight SQL based on their email address?

We have a system that is highly coupled with ExpressionEngine and cannot use the Magento API in many of the EE templates.

Edit to show current login code:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
$session->login($ParticipantInfo['PreferedEmailAddress'],'default_password');
$session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($session->getCustomer());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: As far as i know, even if session data is stored in the db, there is no definite way of telling only via plain SQL.

Question would also be: Which user? Customer, admin or api user? Assuming you store session data within the file system, I could think of some options:

#### API

For API-Users, have a look at the `api_session` table, you can do a join with the `api_user` table, which stores the email address. However, there is no way, the information in these two tables will suffice, as only session id and logdate are saved for a specific user id and you have no way of telling if a session is still active.

Querying for this data those would probably be something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM api_user 
INNER JOIN api_session ON api_user.user_id = api_session.user_id
WHERE api_user.email = "<known_email>"
```

#### Admin & Customer

Admin users are stored within `admin_user`, however, like for `api_user`, no information is stored along for session management.

Customers are stored within the `customer_*` tables. You can look them up in the `log_visitor`table:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM log_visitor_online
INNER JOIN customer_entity ON customer_entity.entity_id = log_visitor_online.customer_id
WHERE c.email = "<known_email>"
```

Again, no information can be retrieved, if the session is still valid. **EDIT**: Tim showed how to do it correctly in his answer.

#### The bad news, in general

No information is stored directly, if a user is logged in currently, only, when the creation date of the session. With out-of-the box functionality you should not be able to tell accurately via SQL if a user is currently logged in or not - this would be insensible at best, as magento checks the user's session's validity against the stored session data in the db/filesystem, so without the user's session data, you can determine nothing with 100% accuracy.

#### The good news if you can write a module

With a little bit of work you can hook into the session management of Magento. There's a [cheat sheet](http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento_events_cheat_sheet/) for events the core ships with. You can also create you own custom events, which you may listen to and execute code upon.

The idea here would be to write a module which could store extra information on the customer (admin or api user vice versa) or within an extra module table. You can hook into the login process and set a timestamp for the api_user/customer/admin has logged in and refresh that timestamp upon a request. If a user's timestamp hasn't been refreshed for, let's say, X Seconds, you assume the user is logged in any more. You delete the user's timestamp upon the logout event.

However, this is also not 100% accurate and it heavily depends on what a user does in you system.

Anyway, I hope I could provide some insight.

lg,

flo

Comment: I guess I could modify the Customer/AccountController to add code in the loginAction and logoutAction to store a value in another table. Thus lies the idiocy in the Magento DB architecture. One of the many reasons we are dumping that piece of **crap** for another e-commerce package.

Comment: There's a lot of events which can be hooked via an `Observer` class, providing a little more fine tuning to the whole process, if you wish. And I congratulate you for the decision :)

Comment: Sorry Florian, but you are a bit wrong about sessions. Magento is storing all info in `log_visitor`, `log_visitor_info` and `log_customer` tables. `log_visitors_online` is used like a sort of temporary table and gets populated only when you visit Customers --> Customers Online page at Magento admin using `prepare` method of `Mage_Log_Model_Resource_Visitor_Online` class. It have nothing to do with sessions.

Comment: jipp, that is correct, wrong assumption here - i leave it as is. Still, it is no accurate measure in my eyes for the problem at hand.

Comment: You can do a curl to the address mentioned having that table populated for you by Magento :D (or essentially just look up the method that populates it and construct an own version of it - still, this is not a plain SQL solution)

Comment: Magento is populating it absolutely the same way as I wrote in my answer. So "Yes" it is possible to get online customers with just one query.

Comment: See my comments on Tim's answer about how we log in customers.